# Using HashMap in place of pointers in Rust

Tags: rust, idioms

It's occurred to me in my adventures with Rust, that indexing into a `HashMap<usize,_>` has many of the same advantages as doing direct heap allocations, but without the difficulties that surround doing the latter in Rust. Treating indexes as pointers, you get:

- Constant-time lookup
- Entities can easily share mutable "references" to a heap value
- None of the clunky `Box`ing business
- You still have Rust's memory safety

I can immediately think of a few disadvantages:

- You're back to having to "manually deallocate" memory until the HashMap itself goes out of scope
- Allocation cost becomes less predictable because of internal resizing

Is this considered an anti-pattern, or is it idiomatic when used for the right use-cases?

Comment: This sounds very similar to an "arena", which certainly has it's use cases.

Comment: You may also be interested in [`slotmap`](https://docs.rs/slotmap/0.3.0/slotmap/).